# Change the color of an horizontal line in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: colors, libreoffice-writer

How to change the color of horizontal lines created with :

```
---
```

or by the menu : Insert -> Horizontal Line -> Simple

The horizontal lines are always in black, and I want to change there colors.

Comment: Loosely related: [Can't remove a line or border in Word 2013](https://superuser.com/q/834020/150988) and [Change the color of an horizontal line in LibreOffice Writer](https://superuser.com/q/548175/150988).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t have access to LibreOffice Writer, but in Microsoft Word, a horizontal line
(as generated by `---`) is a bottom border on the preceding paragraph. 
You can change its attributes (color, thickness, and style, e.g., dotted or dashed)
by selecting the preceding paragraph
and bringing up the “Borders and Shading …” dialog box. 
(If necessary, select the “Paragraph” option in the “Apply to” drop-down,
or whatever LibreOffice Writer has.)

Answer (score 0):

Following settings will still draw the Line in default dark blue color.

[Libre Line drawing Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZU1G.png)

Solution

Click on the left most icon on the toolbar which says `Line COlor`, then draw the line Tadaaaah