# Can't remove a line or border in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

How can I remove this border or line from Ms Word

I can't recall how it got there in the first place, or what it is. And I can't see a borders button in Word 2013. (I see a borders dialog box under the design tab, but no borders button) Pre Word 2013, I'd normally try putting the cursor near it and seeing if a border showed as being there and click none.

[image]

If I try highlighting the whole lot

[image]

Then hitting del

then I end up with 1. and I can't delete it.

Really trying to explain the things that happen when I try to my wrong attempts at deleting and evading them, how they reappear, or appear elsewhere, or  move or don't move.. explaining that isn't that feasible, and hopefully isn't necessary. There should just be some way to delete the things.

I notice the cursor changes to up and down arrows when it hovers over them.. that may help identify what they are. I can't screenshot that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to choose "No Border" option.

Select the paragraph immediately above the line and use the Home Tab->Paragraph Group->Borders button (it's at the bottom right of the group), then click No border.

**edit by barlop- added pics**
[image]

Then (having clicked above/below the border- one would also see the border show in the border button), then as mentioned, choose

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise the borders button was in the 'home' tab until you answered and thus mentioned it.